# Check with PHP if Elasticsearch is still running

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Is there a way with PHP to check if Elasticsearch is running or not?
I want to create a script that checks if the service is still running, and if not it should be started automatically using PHP.

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/ElasticsearchPHP_Endpoints.html#Elasticsearch_Clientping_ping

Answer (score 4):

Hi you can check the health using curl

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/_cluster/health"
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-health.html

i hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

First of all making sure your Elasticsearch service is up all the time, should not be checked by PHP. There are other technologies available to handle such issues e.g. Nagios.

But in case PHP is the only option you have, use below code. You can keep this in cron for every 5 minutes or whatever you feel best.

```
<?php
$command = "ps -aef | grep elasticsearch | grep -v grep | grep '/usr/bin/java'";
exec($command, $pids);
if(count($pids) > 0){
    print_r('elasticsearch service is running!');
}else{
    $command = "service elasticsearch restart";
    exec($command);
    print_r('restarting elasticsearch service.');
}
print_r("\n");
```

Hope this works for you.